# Count the number of sessions over the trailing X days

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a connection log table for customers in our database, and I am trying to count on a daily basis the number of connections each customer has made over the previous seven days.  The source table I'm using has the schema of

```
uuid, sessionuid, connection_timestamp
```

What I want as output is

```
uuid, _date, total_connections_over_trailing_seven_days,
```

so that I can see for a given customer account and given date, how many times that person has connected in the past seven (or whatever) previous days.

The query I have written to accomplish this is

```
SELECT
  uuid, 
  connection_timestamp::date as _date, 
  COUNT(sessionuid) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp_session ROWS 6 PRECEDING) as trailing_seven_day_session_count
FROM connection_history_table
```

But when I execute this query, I get a separate line for each user and every connection_timestamp in the source table instead of a single record for each unique connection_timestamp::date.  Furthermore, the value in the trailing_seven_day_session_count increases from 1 to a maximum value of 7 (if there are at least 7 sessions on a given day), but does not increase after that.  So it seems like I'm counting the number of sessions in a particular day, but only over the first 7 sessions.

```
uuid     _date              trailing_seven_day_session_count
16398   2015-02-18 00:00:00 1
16398   2015-02-18 00:00:00 2
16398   2015-02-18 00:00:00 3
16398   2015-02-18 00:00:00 4
16398   2015-02-18 00:00:00 5
16398   2015-02-18 00:00:00 6
16398   2015-02-18 00:00:00 7
16398   2015-02-18 00:00:00 8
16398   2015-02-18 00:00:00 8
16398   2015-02-25 00:00:00 1
16398   2015-02-25 00:00:00 2
16398   2015-02-25 00:00:00 3
16398   2015-02-25 00:00:00 4
16398   2015-02-25 00:00:00 5
16398   2015-02-25 00:00:00 6
16398   2015-02-25 00:00:00 7
16398   2015-02-25 00:00:00 8
16398   2015-02-25 00:00:00 8
```

I'm new to using window functions, it's not clear to me what I'm doing incorrect here. I've tried doing a partition by connection_timestamp::date but that didn't help either.  I'm basically grasping at straws, and doing so unsuccessfully.

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to count the sessions for each day and then do the sum of the previous days. Something like this:

```
select
    uuid,
    day,
    sum(sessions) over (partition by uuid order by day rows 6 preceding) as trailing_seven_day_session_count
from (select uuid, connection_timestamp::date as day, count(*) sessions
    from connection_history_table
    group by 1,2)
order by 1,2
```

Regarding Brad's comment about sparse data, here is a possible approach. It generates zero records to fill the days so looking back a set number of records will correlate to days. Haven't ran this, but it should be pretty close. Since it generates days it needs an overall time range that needs to be tweaked. I'm not sure I got the day ranges and padding right...it is trying to get 37 days worth of data to generate records for 30 days.

```
with days as (
    -- hack to generate days in redshift like a generate_series function
    select (dateadd(day, -row_number() over (order by true), sysdate::date)) as day
            from stv_blocklist limit 37
),
day_counts as (
    select uuid, connection_timestamp::date as day, count(*) sessions
    from connection_history_table
    where connection_timestamp >= sysdate-37
    group by 1,2
),
zero_days as (
    select s.uuid, d.day, 0 as sessions
    from (
        select distinct uuid from connection_history_table
        where connection_timestamp >= sysdate-37
    ) s
    cross join days d
)
select
    uuid,
    day,
    sum(sessions) over (partition by uuid order by day rows 6 preceding) as trailing_seven_day_session_count
from (
    select uuid, day, sessions from day_counts
    union all
    select uuid, day, sessions from zero_days z
        left join day_counts c on z.uuid=c.uuid and z.day=c.day
        where c.uuid is null
)
having day >= sysdate-30
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried something like that but it doesn't get quite what I want because it counts over the preceding six rows, and I don't necessarily have a row for everyday.  I only have a row for everyday that a user played.  So I have to come up with a totally different solution.  Thanks for your help though.  I'm going to upvote your solution and accept it because it solves the original problem I posted, just not the problem I actually have. :

Comment: Does it have to be a once time shot or can you run the query iteratively...say once a day? If you can do it daily you can add a where clause to the inner select which only selects records where connection_timestamp >= sysdate-7 to get what you want.

Comment: Added janky query to deal with null days.